# href links duplicating the folder in the path every time i click a new link

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have this folder structure

```
frontend -index.html 
         -about.html
         -map.html
```

Then I access them with links as follows

```
 <a href="./frontend/about.html"  class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary" >Learn more</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="./frontend/page2.html"> Map <span class="sr-only">
```

yet if I click a second link the url appears as follows

```
Cannot GET /frontend/frontend/about.html
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, the first click takes me to the page with the correct url, then subsequent clicks just duplicate the folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot: `href="/frontend/about.html"`

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that was how the dot functioned

Comment: Please upvote and accept the solution if it was helpful :)